How to send a protobuf using REST
I am trying to experiment with protobufs over REST. I have created 2 spring boot applications; one to send a prototbuf message (using restTemplate) and the other one consumes it from the exposed REST endpoint and returns a response.
I am able to send a protobuf message but I want to try and send the message using a rest client (such as postman) but cannot.
Is it possible to send a protobuf message using Postman ?

Postman does not support sending binary data in the specific format required for Protocol Buffers (protobuf) directly through its native interface. You can call by node.js with code as you did java code.

I'm not sure why you want to do so but you can always convert your binary to base64 on the sender and then covert it back to the array of bytes on the receiver
